# Why explicitly non-dispatchable methods in Iterator are dispatchable?

Tags: rust

Rust reference [object-safety](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/items/traits.html#object-safety) confused me for a while, and says:

> Explicitly non-dispatchable functions require:
>
> Have a where Self: Sized bound (receiver type of Self (i.e. self) implies this).

But I found `code::iter::Iterator` has dozen of methods are declared as **explicitly non-dispatchable functions**, one of them below:

```
pub trait Iterator {
    ...
    fn count(self) -> usize
    where
        Self: Sized,
    {
        self.fold(
            0,
            #[rustc_inherit_overflow_checks]
            |count, _| count + 1,
        )
    }
    ...
}
```

However, all of them are dispatchable by trait-object at [rust-playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=52b6579ff69847f92903893d682d713e):

```
fn main() {
    let it: &mut dyn Iterator<Item = u32> = &mut [1, 2, 3].into_iter();
    assert_eq!(3, it.count()); // ok
}
```

That is good, I start try to implements a worked example, but it can not be dispatched at [rust-playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=6a71b632c53827403d6dc37a9df10b59), and report compiler error: "**the `dispatch` method cannot be invoked on a trait object**" that is expected:

```rust
fn main() {
    pub trait Sup {
        fn dispatch(self) -> String
        where
            Self: Sized,
        {
            "sup".to_string()
        }
    }

    struct Sub;
    impl Sup for Sub {
        fn dispatch(self) -> String {
            "sub".to_string()
        }
    }

    let it: &mut dyn Sup = &mut Sub;
    assert_eq!("trait", it.dispatch());
}
```

Why explicitly non-dispatchable methods in `code::iter::Iterator` are dispatchable? Is there any magic which I didn't found?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason is simple, if we think of this: what type we're invoking the method `count` on?

Is it `dyn Iterator<Item = u32>`? Let's check:

```
assert_eq!(3, <dyn Iterator<Item = u32>>::count(it));
```

Nope, there are two errors:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
 --> src/main.rs:3:53
  |
3 |     assert_eq!(3, <dyn Iterator<Item = u32>>::count(it));
  |                                                     ^^ expected trait object `dyn Iterator`, found mutable reference
  |
  = note:   expected trait object `dyn Iterator<Item = u32>`
          found mutable reference `&mut dyn Iterator<Item = u32>`

error[E0277]: the size for values of type `dyn Iterator<Item = u32>` cannot be known at compilation time
   --> src/main.rs:3:53
    |
3   |     assert_eq!(3, <dyn Iterator<Item = u32>>::count(it));
    |                   --------------------------------- ^^ doesn't have a size known at compile-time
    |                   |
    |                   required by a bound introduced by this call
    |
    = help: the trait `Sized` is not implemented for `dyn Iterator<Item = u32>`
note: required by a bound in `count`
```

OK, well... is it `&mut dyn Iterator`, then?

```
assert_eq!(3, <&mut dyn Iterator<Item = u32>>::count(it));
```

Now it compiles. It's understandable that the second error goes away - `&mut T` is always `Sized`. But why do the `&mut dyn Iterator` has access to the method of `Iterator`?

The answer is in the documentation. First, `dyn Iterator` obviously implements `Iterator` - that's true for any trait. Second, there's [implementation of `Iterator`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/core/iter/trait.Iterator.html#impl-Iterator-85) for any `&mut I`, where `I: Iterator + ?Sized` - which our `dyn Iterator` satisfies.

---

Now, one may ask - what code is executed when we use this implementation? After all, `count` requires consuming `self`, so calling it on reference can't delegate to the `dyn Iterator` - otherwise we'd be back to square one, dispatching non-dispatchable.

Here, the answer lies in the structure of the `Iterator` trait. As one can see, it has only a single required method, namely [`next`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#tymethod.next), which takes `&mut self`; all other methods are *provided*, that is, they have some default implementations using `next` - for example, [here's it for `count`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.58.0/src/core/iter/traits/iterator.rs.html#195-206):

```
fn count(self) -> usize
where
    Self: Sized,
{
    self.fold(
        0,
        #[rustc_inherit_overflow_checks]
        |count, _| count + 1,
    )
}
```

where `fold`, in turn, is [the following](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.58.0/src/core/iter/traits/iterator.rs.html#2161-2174):

```
fn fold<B, F>(mut self, init: B, mut f: F) -> B
where
    Self: Sized,
    F: FnMut(B, Self::Item) -> B,
{
    let mut accum = init;
    while let Some(x) = self.next() {
        accum = f(accum, x);
    }
    accum
}
```

As you can see, knowing just the `next`, compiler can derive `fold` and then `count`.

Now, back to our `&mut dyn Iterator`s. Let's check how, exactly, this implementation looks like; it appears to be [quite simple](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.58.0/src/core/iter/traits/iterator.rs.html#2161-2174):

```
#[stable(feature = "rust1", since = "1.0.0")]
impl<I: Iterator + ?Sized> Iterator for &mut I {
    type Item = I::Item;
    #[inline]
    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<I::Item> {
        (**self).next()
    }
    fn size_hint(&self) -> (usize, Option<usize>) {
        (**self).size_hint()
    }
    fn advance_by(&mut self, n: usize) -> Result<(), usize> {
        (**self).advance_by(n)
    }
    fn nth(&mut self, n: usize) -> Option<Self::Item> {
        (**self).nth(n)
    }
}
```

You can see that the `&self` and `&mut self` methods, i.e. the ones which can be called on the trait object, are forwarded by the reference to the inner value and dispatched dynamically.

The `self` methods, i.e. the ones which *cannot* use the trait object, are dispached statically using their default implementation, which consume the reference and pass it, eventually, into one of these - non-consuming, dynamically-dispatched - methods.

Comment: Great, you helped me, thanks. rust implementions make my head dizzy. How did you find that secret?

Comment: It's a common idiom for standard library traits - to have an `impl<T: Trait> Trait for &mut T` (or for `&T`, whatever makes sense). For example, the same thing is available for `Read` - it is auto-implemented on `&mut impl Read`: https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/io/trait.Read.html#impl-Read-13.

Comment: You are right, but I found this way does not support dynamic dispatch, `&mut T` and `&T` will have inherent default implementation for static dispatch, am I right?

Comment: Updated the answer - hopefully this clarifies this point.

Comment: thanks your detailed answer. Happy New Year!